# Can I use SqlConnection.BeginTransaction inside TransactionScope block

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, transactions, transactionscope

I have something like this:

```
      Dim options As New TransactionOptions With {.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, .Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue}

            Using scope As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options)


                'Do some db operations
                MyLibrary.ExecuteTransaction()

                scope.Complete()
            End Using
```

And inside my library I have something like this

```
Public Function ExecuteTransaction()
  SqlDim transaction As SqlTransaction
            transaction = cConn.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction")
  'Do some db operations
  transaction.commit()
End Function
```

But sometimes I got an exception in MyLibrary:

```
Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.
at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
```

I have my Application Server in one machine and my Database Server and another machine. The MSDTC is configured in bouth servers to accept remote transactions.

¿Can anyone help me?

Comment: In principle I don't see why you couldn't use it, but you complete the transaction scope before starting your "manual" transaction, and you do not seem to dispose your "manual" transactions, which might or might not be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I correct it yet. The complete() method is called after the call to the library

Comment: Even if you can, why would you?  Why would you mix those two methods of creating transactions?

Comment: MyLibrary.dll is a legacy project. I need to use it in my project. My transaction (TransactionScope) involves the call to these library.

Comment: No you can't have multiple tranacations against the same connection. When you create a TransactionScope, it does the heavy work of creating transactions for you (like the SqlTransaction). I would have expected a different error though. I assume this is not the code that has the error, but an example? (since it is an ELO error, not a SQLClient error).